# Jquery validation making incorrect appearance of form elements, submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

my php page contain the following html/jquery for password field validation. Below is my code

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:7070/FFTFinals/inverse-php/index.php?getPage=iChgPass" align="center">
Current Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="currentPassword"><span id="currentPassword" class="required"></span>
<br>
New Password:<br>
<input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword"><span id="newPassword" class="required"></span>
<br>
Confirm Password:<br>
<input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword"><span id="confirmPassword" class="required"></span>
<br>
<div class="registrationFormAlert" style="color:green;" id="CheckPasswordMatch">
<script>
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
        var password = $("#newPassword").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#confirmPassword").val();
        if (password != confirmPassword)
            $("#CheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords does not match!");
        else
            $("#CheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#confirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
       
    });
    </script>
<br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is when I input values in new password fields the validation works well but the submit button is disappearing ? is there something I missing ? I found this code snippet from web. Please help to solve this code.

Comment: You failed to close your `#CheckPasswordMatch` div anywhere, so the submit button is part of it, and so naturally it disappears, when you _overwrite_ the whole HTML of that element …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input might be inside the div that's getting it's content replaced using `.html()`. Simply get it out if that's the case. But in your code as is, you're not closing the div properly.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:7070/FFTFinals/inverse-php/index.php?getPage=iChgPass" align="center">
  Current Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="currentPassword"><span id="currentPassword" class="required"></span>
  <br> New Password:<br>
  <input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword"><span id="newPassword" class="required"></span>
  <br> Confirm Password:<br>
  <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword"><span id="confirmPassword" class="required"></span>
  <br>
  <div class="registrationFormAlert" style="color:green;" id="CheckPasswordMatch">
    <script>
      function checkPasswordMatch() {
        var password = $("#newPassword").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#confirmPassword").val();
        if (password != confirmPassword)
          $("#CheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords does not match!");
        else
          $("#CheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#confirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);

      });
    </script>
    <br>
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```